# Is RTCA DO-260 Change 1 the same as DO-260A?

Tags: ads-b, surveillance

I am a bit confused as to the history **and** the naming for 260 documents. This is the timeline I perceived.

From earliest to latest:

1. DO-260                  ( September 13, 2000 )
2. DO-260 Change 1         ( June      27, 2006 )
3. DO-260B                 ( December  2,  2009 )
4. DO-260B Corrigendum 1   ( December  13, 2011 )
5. DO-260B Corrigendum 1   ( December  13, 2011 ).
   This one says it is supplemental to DO-260B for corrections in regards about typographical errors, etc.

Am I missing something? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

---

At the moment I assume DO-260A is the same thing as DO-260 Change 1 yes? Another is what are the major differences between DO-260B and DO-260B Corrigendum 1 ? Thank you in advance.

---

Sources:

[RTCA store website](https://my.rtca.org/nc__store),
[Fourth Meeting of APIRG_ICAO](https://www.icao.int/WACAF/Documents/APIRG/SG/2011/CNS_SG4/docs/wp20_en.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DO-260 change 1 is not DO-260A.

- DO-260A released in April 2003
- DO-260A change 1 in June 2006
- DO-260A change 2 in December 2006

The releases marked as 'change' contain editorial changes, clarifications and corrections, but are effectively the same specification.

The alphabetical versioning is for subsequent releases of a new specification of the same system. In these releases the specification is changed, i.e. the behaviour of the system specified is different.

Comment: Thank you! Also, would you happen to know why RTCA used the number "260?" Well...numbering documents in general really like DO-242, DO-248, etc. What are their reasons for using those numbers ?

Comment: @AghaKusuma the numbers are assigned sequentially. If a RTCA Special Committee wants to publish a new specification, the document will be assigned the next available number. Note that the time between the number assignment and the actual date of publication varies, and so the numbers are published sometimes slightly out of order.

Comment: Also, the Corrigendum is supplemental information, specifically: "This document is a supplement to DO-260B. It contains corrections to typographical errors, corrections to test procedures and notes added to clarify existing text. These changes represent feedback from industry use of the published version of DO-260B. This supplement does not alter any existing requirements and does not affect the compliance of any equipment designed to meet the original published document."

Comment: A clarification on the DO numbers.  When industry or the regulatory agencies determine the need for a specification, plan, guidance, or other document; the request is submitted to the RTCA Program Management Committee (PMC). The PMC will validate the need and publish "Terms of Reference" which defines the document (with number) and assigns the task of generating the document to a Special Committee (SC).